# Enable using time type field in our production

Tags: time

We want to use the new time field in prod. However, it doesn't seem to be available yet in our prod. It seems to be there in our sandboxes though. Is there a way we can enable this beta feature?

Comment: contacting salesforce is the only way as of now to enable it in production.. its enabled by default in sandboxes & dev orgs. ref : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_field_time_type_beta.htm

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thank you, Vamsi. I will open a ticket for that.